# How to call multiple function in OnPressed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

```
Positioned(
          bottom: 25,
          right: 10,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: 'tag1',
              backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.location_searching,
                color: Colors.purple,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                _addGeoPoint();
                _animateToUser();
              }),
        ),
```

**Only _animateToUser Working**

```
_animateToUser() async {
    var pos = await location.getLocation();
    mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(pos.latitude, pos.longitude), zoom: 17.0)));
  }
```

**_addGeoPoint not Working**

```
Future<DocumentReference> _addGeoPoint() async {
    var pos = await location.getLocation();
    final coordinates = Coordinates(pos.latitude, pos.longitude);
    var addresses =
        await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
    var first = addresses.first;
    print("${first.featureName} : ${first.addressLine}");
//    GeoFirePoint point =
//        geo.point(latitude: pos.latitude, longitude: pos.longitude);
    return _firestore.collection('location').add({
      'UserLocation': first.featureName,
      'UserLocationName': first.addressLine
    });
  }
```

But when i changed onPressed to

```
onPressed: _addGeopoint,
```

The _addGeopoint works.

i cant call both function one time.

Comment: try this `onPressed:()=>[_addGeoPoint(),_animateToUser()]`

Comment: Try to convert your `onPressed` callback into `async` and use the `await` keyword before both the methods. like 
`onPressed: () async {
   await _addGeoPoint();
   await _animateToUser();
}
`

Comment: @AbhilashChandran That actually works. But it takes time to load. Is there any other fast option

Comment: @RahulChokshi that I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: @AsbahRiyas duration of the call depends on what you do in these functions.  This can only be identified by timing these execution like printing time before and after the await in these methods to see the timing. One thing I see is you are calling `await location.getLocation();` in both methods. Maybe you can move this out and pass this info to both the methods and hence avoid one long call.

Comment: @RahulChokshi i had written this function as per your command                 
    Future getThelocation() async {
    var pos = await location.getLocation();
    return geogo.Coordinates(pos.latitude, pos.longitude);
  }                                                                                                                                                       but it says i cant use future inside a asynchronous call when i call this function on my both methods

Answer (score 0):

As you are using async and await inside the function you need to put try/catch and put return statement inside catch. In case any exception occurs or due to some other reasons it's not able to move further, it won't call the second function. Please check the below example for same.

```
onPressed: () {
     _funOne();
     _funTwo();
}),


_funOne() async{
  try {
    await location.getLocation()(); 
    // your code...
  } catch (e) {
    return;
  }
}

_funTwo() async{
  try {
    await location.getLocation()(); 
    // your code...
  } catch (e) {
    return;
  }
}
```